# How can I stop by cat from coming on kitchen counter

Tags: cats, behavior

I have a savannah cat that is 6 months old. She keeps jumping on our kitchen counters and kitchen table. We’ve sprayed her with water mixed with vinegar and it doesn’t do anything. Today she licked food I had cooked that I put aside to cool. We are first time cat owners and I’m done with her but my husband and kids refuses to give her away lol. Plz help!!